# Check if a string contains other characters than

Tags: php

I would like to check for the skype username inserted on my website, and so I want to check if the username entered by the user doesn't match this :

> A Skype username cannot be shorter than six characters or longer than
>   32. It can contain both letters and numbers, but must start with a letter; accented characters are not allowed. The only punctuation
>   marks you can use are commas, dashes, periods and underscores.

I tried with preg but can't find something fine because I never worked with it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern.
First part makes sure it's a letter then it can be any of your listed character between 5 and 31 (+ the first letter = 6-32).

```
$str = 'Username1';

preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.,_-]{5,31}/', $str, $match);

If(isset($match[0])){
    Echo "valid username";
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/uTVlIX/2